# Trouble and needed clarification for Itunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, game-center

I am adding game center to my application and I feel lost. First of all,, my app is nmot a game, but I want people to see thier friends "score". Will I have to classify the app as a game? I am working on adding my app to itunes connect but I dont quite get it. When I add it and select the distribution date, will I have to distribute it? What happens when that day is reached? Do I even need to do all this to use gamecenter in my beta version? How does the app know its connected to itunes connect? Sorrty if these are stupid questiopns, but I dont quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app uses Game Center, the most typical thing is that it was classified by you as a game. We don't know how, and especially who, will review your app, so it could pass the review process, though. 
Let's see two things:
- if you need to show a leaderboard, but the app is not a game, you could create your own leaderboard, or use a third party leaderboard (eg Google's).
- different questions are those that you pose in the end of your  multiple "question".  I suggest you look for each one of those in the Internet. Shortly, the date of public release depends on app submission and approval. If the date for public release is 1/1/2011 and you send the app to Apple, when it is approved it will automatically be published. You shouldn't send beta versions to Apple. The Game Center features should be available in sandbox mode while developing (please look for those terms in the Internet).

Comment: ok, but one last question that im still not sure about. What will happen when i add my app to itunes connect? Will I have to submit the app on the date i chose? Also, i heard you will lose your name of the app after 90 days, is this correct?

Comment: So the thing is: the release date in iTunes Connect doesn't matter at all. You will not have any problems if they approve your app later than the date you specified. In fact, the equation could be: if (release_date) <= (approval date) then the app is automatically approved. Otherwise, the app will be pending for developer release.   I hadn't heard about the app name problem, but you're right, [only it's 120 days](http://forums.toucharcade.com/archive/index.php/t-82876.html)